# MS Access Subreport Grouping and Sorting Issues

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

been pulling my hair out with this one.  Searched everywhere and can't get anythign to work.  Here's my scenario:

I have a report with several subreports from linked tables. I would like to group the subreports to sort on a given field based on the value of a variable called SORT_BY, and force a page break for each value., i.e. Group a subreport on ItemDescription or ItemLocation.  The SORT_BY variable is set from a users prefs dialog. (ya, I'm using it like a constant but the user can change it)

Now, I want the user to be able to preview the report before they print.  I have the report being launched in ReportView mode.  This allows me to place a "Print" button and a "Close" button in the header of the report (which do not print).  I have it set this way because the user is locked out of the normal "ribbon" and other controls so I have to provide buttons.  The buttons do not show up in PrintPreview mode.

Obviously, I need to accomplish this via VBA.  I can't seem to get GroupLevel settings to work.  I've tried a CreateGroupLevel function to no avail.  Tried with existing groups and with no existing groups.  I've tried abandoning the group idea and simply tried to Sort the subreports using the OrderBy property, and nothing works.  I'm going crazy.

Does anyone have any suggestions... other than giving up? :-)

UPDATE:
I've been trying the CreateGrouplevel function before opening the main report.  i.e. open each subreport in design view, add the group, close the subform, then open the main report.  However, when I try to implement the CreateGroupLevel function, I get the error:

Run-time error '2154':
You can't call this function when the Group, Sort, and Total Pane is open.

I don't understand this.  Here is my code:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport strReport, acViewDesign
intGroupLevel = CreateGroupLevel(strReport, "FluorescentDescription", True, False)
DoCmd.Close acReport, strReport
```

Thoughts?

OOOPS!

Ok, so I figured out te '2154' error.  Silly really, if you have EVER turned on the Group, Sort, Total Pane while editing a report, it will automatically be turned on every time you enter Design View on that report until you physically turn it off.  Strange.  Still chipping away at this.

Comment: So, you have a subreport in the details area and you want to change to sort field for it? Did I understand that right?

Comment: Correct.  In fact, I'll have several subreports in the detail area.  I'd like to be able to set a 'group' or at least set the 'sort' field based upon a variable set by the user. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I sure someone will correct me if I am wrong, however I don't think putting the buttons on the report will work. Why not build your own custom toolbar to display that contains Print and Close

Comment: Well, the buttons work great in Report View.  They are there when you are "viewing" the report, but are not included when "printing".  It's great.  I just can't figure out how to manipulate subreport groups and sorting via VBA.  Thanks for the reply.